# Get indicated string in list

Tags: python

I got the list such as:

```
[Margaret, Peter, Julia-noCP-L,Parker-CP-T, Jessica, Monica-CP-T, Mark, Peter-noCP]
```

I want to obtain or objects which contain only CP in string:

```
['Parker-CP-T', 'Monica-CP-T']
```

I made it in the following way:

```
headers = ['Margaret', 'Peter', 'Julia-noCP-L', 'Parker-CP-T', 'Jessica', 'Monica-CP-T', 'Mark, Peter-noCP']

headers_CPs = []
    for i in headers:
            if "CP" in i:
                    headers_CPs.append(i)

filtr = filter(lambda x: x.split('-')[1] != "noCP", headers_CPs)
print filter
```

I want to learn how to write efficient codes. Therefore I want to ask you whether you have some ideas how to solve that simple task easier. Maybe on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). With that you can do something like this:

```
headers_CP = [x for x in headers if 'CP' in x]
```

This will pull out all items in the list `headers` that contain the string 'CP'.

Answer (score 0):

One way is just accepting the items that are contain `-CP-` instead of checking the existence of `CP` and then filtering the result. You can do this within a [*list comprehension*](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html):

```
[item for item in headers if '-CP-' in item]
```

If you are not sure about the delimiter (here `'-'`) you can check it with regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> headers = ['Margaret', 'Peter', 'Julia-noCP-L', 'Parker-CP-T', 'Jessica', 'Monica-CP-T', 'Mark, Peter-noCP']
>>> [item for item in headers if re.search(r'\bCP\b', item)]
['Parker-CP-T', 'Monica-CP-T']
```

The regular expression `r'\bCP\b'` will only match the `CP` literals that are surrounded with none-word characters (`\b` is a word boundary modifier in regex).